# Add transparent background to ffmpeg with text over it

Tags: ffmpeg

How to correctly add expression to transparent background like on this question [ffmpeg drawtext filter - create transparent background with text](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/15551/ffmpeg-drawtext-filter-create-transparent-background-with-text)
for my case (where there are 3 lines in bottom right corner):

```
ffmpeg -i videoin.mp4 -vf "[in]drawtext=enable='between(t,2.5,6.5)':fontsize=50:fontcolor=White:fontfile='ariblk.ttf':text='textline1':x=min(4*(tw\+10)-(abs(4-2*(t-2.5)))*(tw+10)-tw\,10):y=h-th-130, drawtext=enable='between(t,2.5,6.5)':fontsize=50:fontcolor=White:fontfile='ariblk.ttf':text='textline2':x=min(4*(tw\+10)-(abs(4-2*(t-2.5)))*(tw+10)-tw\,10):y=h-th-75, drawtext=enable='between(t,2.5,6.5)':fontsize=50:fontcolor=White:fontfile='ariblk.ttf':text='textline3':x=min(4*(tw\+10)-(abs(4-2*(t-2.5)))*(tw+10)-tw\,10):y=h-th-20[out]" -codec:a copy videoout.mp4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the box options i.e.

```
drawtext=enable='between(t,2.5,6.5)':fontsize=50:fontcolor=White:fontfile='ariblk.ttf':text='textline1':x=min(4*(tw\+10)-(abs(4-2*(t-2.5)))*(tw+10)-tw\,10):y=h-th-130:box=1:boxborderw=12:boxcolor=black@0.45
```

This adds a box with padding of 12 pixels around the text boundary, and the color is black with 45% opacity.

Using **drawbox** (add it before the drawtexts)

```
drawbox=y=ih-140:h=110:c=black@0.45:t=max:enable='between(t,2.5,6.5)'
```

---

Here's the entire vf expression:

```
-vf "drawbox=y=ih-140:h=110:c=black@0.45:t=max:enable='between(t,2.5,6.5)',drawtext=enable='between(t,2.5,6.5)':fontsize=50:fontcolor=White:fontfile='ariblk.ttf':text='textline1':x=min(4*(tw\+10)-(abs(4-2*(t-2.5)))*(tw+10)-tw\,10):y=h-th-130, drawtext=enable='between(t,2.5,6.5)':fontsize=50:fontcolor=White:fontfile='ariblk.ttf':text='textline2':x=min(4*(tw\+10)-(abs(4-2*(t-2.5)))*(tw+10)-tw\,10):y=h-th-75, drawtext=enable='between(t,2.5,6.5)':fontsize=50:fontcolor=White:fontfile='ariblk.ttf':text='textline3':x=min(4*(tw\+10)-(abs(4-2*(t-2.5)))*(tw+10)-tw\,10):y=h-th-20" -codec:a copy videoout.mp4
```

Comment: Thx Mulvya, but i was thinking about drawbox so the background can be in full width. With 3 lines that have different number of letters it looks ugly this way. I am using y=h-th-130 up to y=h-th-20 for those 3 lines, so the background should be from around 140 to 10, but in full width, as i might add more text or image over it in right corner later. And from the link in question it looks perfect (not the position but background).

Comment: Thx Mulvya !. I am getting error "Unable to parse graph description substring. Might be that i am not separating text and box expressions correctly. Starting like this ffmpeg -i videoin.mp4 -vf drawbox=y=ih-140:h=110:c=black@0.45:t=max:enable='between(t,2.5,6.5)': "[in]drawtext=enable='between(t,2.5,6.5)'....etc...